# How to install the xmlrpc client command on macOS

Tags: macos, xml-rpc

I need to install the xmlrpc command line client on my mac. I tried Macports and Homebrew but they don't install the  xmlrpc command line function.
I guess that's because the default install of xmlrpc-c doesn't include the xmlrpc comman line tool :

> Because the utility programs are not essential to the package, the
> default install tools don't install them at all. The builder does
> build them, though, and if you build Xmlrpc-c from source, you will
> find them all in the tools/ directory.

But I need this tool, I tried to compible xmlrpc-c with

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ && make && make install
```

But it threw errors like :

asprintf.c:132:10: error: implicit declaration of function 'vasprintf' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

So does someone did it on a mac ?
Thanks